# How getting ManyToManyField("self") in the template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, self, django-orm

I don't figure out how getting the value of sequels in the template.

here models.py

```
class Anno( models.Model ):
    anno = models.CharField( max_length=4 )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.anno
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Anni"

class Film( models.Model ):
    titolo = models.CharField( max_length=39 )
    trama = models.TextField( max_length=1000 )
    anno = models.ForeignKey( Anno )

    generi = models.ManyToManyField( Genere_Film )


    sequels = models.ManyToManyField( "self", blank=True )


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titolo + " " + self.trama
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Films"
```

In the template I used:

```
{% for generi in film.generi.all %}{{ generi.genere }}{% endfor %}
```

But now I don't know what I have to write in the template. Help me please.

here views.py

```
def film(request, id):
    film = get_object_or_404( Film, pk=id )
    return render_to_response('Film.html', { 'film': film })
```

I added something for the question in the comment.

Comment: For further questions you need to start a new question...

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way:

```
{% for sequel in film.sequels.all %}{{ sequel.titolo }}{% endfor %}
```

If there aren't any sequels, use `{% empty %}`

```
{% for sequel in film.sequels.all %}
   {{ sequel.titolo }}
{% empty %}
   <p>No sequels</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry I had tried but I think I hadn't add the sequel before...thanks

Comment: If I want to order the element of sequel by "anno" how I have to write in the template or view or model? Thanks...

Comment: in the view, there you'll add a [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work because there is film = get_object_or_404( Film, pk=id )